# Navigating through different section in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to move  cursor through specific paragraph/section  on clicking of a `particular key`.

how to to achieve this in CKEditor 5

```
editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keydown', ( evt, data ) => {

   if ( data.keyCode == 39 ) {
    //move cursor to next paragraph or element  with some specific id
   }
 } );
```